navigation to definitions not working in js inside HTML files in VsCode
Trials for both of my Webstorm and Enterprise version of Intellij have exprired, so to be able to work with the JS/HTML/CSS part of my project, I am trying to switch to VsCode for the time being.
Right off the bat, I faced a problem with not being navigate to definitions of anything i.e. not just entities in my code, but even native functions e.g. getElementById():

I've found similar questions being asked about this, but looks like in those situations certain frameworks (e.g. Angular) caused trouble for VsCode. My project though is just using plain vanilla JS and nothing fancy.
Does anyone know how to resolve that?
I am using the latest VsCode at the moment i.e. ver 1.89 of April 2024.
Update May 6, 2024:
Apparently, the issue is specific to js which resides inside my html file i.e. navigation doesn't work only in the local js inside of the html file, but works fine inside of external js files referenced in the html file.
Also, changing language mode of the html file from 'HTML' to 'JavaScript' doesn't fix the issue.

this should work just fine. does this also happen after closing the current workspace, and creating a new untitled file with the language mode set to "JavaScript" and the file only containing document.getElementById?

Thank you for your suggestion.
Apparently, when trying it out, I figured out that the issue I am facing is specific only to js which resides inside my html file i.e. navigation doesn't work only in the local js inside of the html file, but works fine inside the external files referenced in the html file.
Going to update my orinal question accordingly.
BTW, trying to fix the issue by changing language mode of the html file from 'HTML' to 'JavaScript' didn't help.

Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

To begin with, you need to understand what a Webstorm is an IDE, and VSCode is CodeEditor. getElementById is a browser API method and VSCode don't know anything about outside documentation. But you can find and install any extentions for VSCode.
Also try hover and click method with holding Alt button.
definition exemple

this is false. VS Code ships with builtin support for JS and the DOM API via TypeScript. see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/78046082. and the modifier in VS Code for go to definition is ctrl/cmd- not alt.

You're posting an opinion about IDE preferences, which isn't accurate as VS Code is an IDE just like Webstorm.
